# Flutter Google Sign In super slow on Android

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-authentication

I am currently testing my Flutter app on my Android Device. I have added sign in with Google using Firebase. On iOS everything works just fine, and also Android Emulators works good.

On my physical Samsung Device however, things are not as smooth.

I have this when you press the Google Sign In Button:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Trigger the authentication flow
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

  // Obtain the auth details from the request
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
      await googleUser?.authentication;

  // Create a new credential
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(. <--- This takes forever
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  final authResult =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  return authResult.user;
}
```

Creating the `credential` variable it takes forever (minutes). Later in the pipeline, I am loading data from my Firebase database.

Just this line

`final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(usersKey).get();`

takes minutes to complete. I have never experienced this before. Surfing on my device and the WIFI works just fine.

I updated my Android device as much as possible and then it worked as expected. Can it be that it does not work on older Android Versions? Seems like this feature is something that almost all apps are using and should work?

Comment: Hello, have you fixed this one? I am encountering the same situation when I am trying to test it on a real device using ``flutter run --release``. However in emulators, it works smoothly.

Comment: No, not really. Very disturbing.

Comment: What you think the problem is? Is this a code based problem or from firebase auth? It's been days sometimes it is faster for me and sometimes it is so slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify particular scope.

But first:

- One needs to have OAuth Consent Screen with (at least) all non-restricted scopes
- add `googleapis` dependency to pubspec

I was playing around with the scopes combination:

```
GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        // people.PeopleServiceApi.userEmailsReadScope,
        people.PeopleServiceApi.userinfoEmailScope,
        // firebase.FirebaseDynamicLinksApi.firebaseScope
      ]).signIn();
```

And also these imports:

```
import 'package:googleapis/people/v1.dart' as people;
import 'package:googleapis/firebasedynamiclinks/v1.dart' as firebase;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually figured out the reason. On Wifi router there was a DNS issue - after restarting the router the issue went away on the physical device. In order to test - try using mobile data as well in order to compare with WiFi